# Show product blocks based on product id

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, widget

I am new to Magento.

I have some product ids. I have to list this product on my custom page. These products are selected from different categories. So I cant make these products in same category and display using insert widgets.

If my product ids are 23, 32, 12, 583. How can I display these products on a page?

> UPDATE

i write the following code in my custom file `(app/design/frontend/Alothemes/bencher6/Magento_Theme/templates/myphp/myphpcode.phtml)`

```
 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(20);
```

and I write the block in cms section

```
 {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::myphp/myphpcode.phtml"}}
```

so I get the following error  **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage'**

Please help.

Comment: using hardcoded ids is bad. you should first think about what identifies these products

Comment: take a look at viewmodels

Comment: is there any extension to do this

Comment: i don't think you need an extension. just use widgets

Comment: please attach phtml file code

Comment: only i write this code  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(20);